# Stacking multiple TV hats

Tags: hat, television-tuner

Is it possible to stack multiple TV hats on each other?

I would like multiple users to watch TV channels on different frequencies (MUXes).

Comment: But you can only decode one mux at a time.  Even you can demux mux, there is only one HDMI output on Rpi.

Comment: @tlfong01 I use raspi as a TV stream server -> hence multiple users can watch TV at same time.

Comment: @tlfong01 Can you PLS explain what do you mean by `Even you can demux mux` ?

Comment: Yes. I agree that you can use Rpi as a video stream server, therefore MULTIPLE users can watch the SAME VIDEO (say, same movie) at the SAME TIME. Now let me think aloud slowly.  Suppose you can stack two TV HATs on one Rpi, and that one HAT decodes one mux (Movie A say) and the second HAT decodes another mux (Movie B say).  Now you want your stream server to entertain two users, one user watching Movie A, and the other user watching Movie B.  I am just guessing what you wish to do.  Perhaps you can counter suggest what you wish to do.

Comment: @tlfong01 That is 100% correct :) Generally I want my stream server to entertain multiple users, watching movies from multiple MUX-es.

Comment: As answer says,  (1) the SPI chip select problem.  For me it is not a problem, because I almost always do not use any Rpi's built in CE0,1 pins.  Instead I demux other GPIO pins shifted up to 5V and use software to do my own CE0 to CEn control.  I also use GPIO extender MCP23017 GPIO pins as my own CEn pins.  In other words, I can select 16 HATs or more, BUT I don't know if Rpi can control many selected TV HATs at the same time (No problem for my sensors, latched IO devices etc). (2) HAT EEPROM ID driver load problem.  You need to cheat the Rpi by activating one HAT at a time.

Comment: Above are just brainstorming.  I would rather simply use, say 4 slave Rpi's each with one HAT, and use one master rpi to do all the control and user interface.

Comment: And about mux/demux: 
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=233311&sid=389fde6a4505be673c015cc1f9075118#p1429069.

Comment: @tlfong01 So it is not possible out of the box. I see you quite into Raspis :). Good luck with them. Anyway, thank you for the effort.

Comment: You are welcome.  Messing around electronics is one of my hobbies.  I also enjoy solving electronics problems.  Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible because there's no way to change the SPI chip select pin from CE0.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=227520
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=247569